# Swift Error: "Value of type 'ClassResult' has no member 'classification'

Tags: swift

I'm developing on Swift 4.0.1 using Xcode 9.1 and I'm trying to control the type of data shown in the debug console when I run Visual Recognition on my app. So I've tried cleaning this project, restarting Xcode, copying and pasting code from the downloaded project and checking for misspells. I've tried nearly everything. Stackoverflow questions about similar cases don't help because it's all different case scenarios and of older swift (3 and 2). I've tried adding an "_" like this:`classificationResults.append(classes[index]._classification)` like one person said it worked for them, and it still shows the error "Value of type 'ClassResult' has no member 'classification'.

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbllb.png)

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        imageView.image = image

        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        let visualRecognition = VisualRecognition(apiKey: apiKey, version: version)

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.01)

        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("tempImage.jpg")

        try? imageData?.write(to: fileURL, options: [])


        visualRecognition.classify(imagesFile: fileURL, success: { (classifiedImages) in

            let classes = classifiedImages.images.first!.classifiers.first!.classes

            self.classificationResults = []

            for index in 0..<classes.count {
                classificationResults.append(classes[index].classification)
            }
            print(classifiedImages)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.cameraButton.isEnabled = true
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                self.shareButton.isHidden = false
            }

            if self.classificationResults.contains("hotdog") {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.navigationItem.title = "Hotdog!"
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
                    self.topBarImageView.image = UIImage(named:"hotdog")

                }
            }

            else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.navigationItem.title = "Not Hotdog!"
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
                    self.topBarImageView.image = UIImage(named:"not-hotdog")
                }

            }

        })


    } else {
        print("There was an error picking the image")
    }[][1]
```

Comment: I'm guessing your `classificationResults` variable is of type `ClassResult` so it would be helpful if you included that code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, ClassResult does not have a member named classification, but does have one named className.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/blob/master/Source/VisualRecognitionV3/Models/ClassResult.swift

Comment: I put it in and the error disappeared. Now, however, the debug console doesn't show anything at all when I use a photo like it used to. Does it refer to something different from what used to be the "classification"?  Because I was following a course (still fairly recent) that worksd with "classification".